# React Native Signature Canvas crashes in production

Tags: react-native, webview, crash, expo, production-environment

I integrated the react-native-signature-canvas in my expo app.

It works fine in development and also works if I build the apk through expo.

But it crashes of I make android app bundle(aab) using eas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have installed React Native WebView as it's mentioned in documentation

> This package depends on react-native-webview and it is particularly
> needed when you are using React Native CLI. To install
> react-native-webview

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this bug by installing **react-native-webview** manually in expo and updating **react-native-signature-canvas** to a newer version